# Azure Server Incaccessible

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

One of my 10 **Azure VMs** running windows has suddenly became inaccessible! Azure Management Console shows the state of this VM as "running" the Dashboard shows no server activity since my last **RDP** logout **16 hours** ago. I tried restarting the instance with no success, still inaccessible ( No **RDP** access, hosted application down, unsuccessful ping...).

I have changed the instance size from **A5** to **A6** using the management portal and everything went back to normal. Windows event viewer showed no errors except the unexpected shutdown today after my Instance size change. Nothing was logged between my RDP logout yesterday and the system startup today after changing the size.

I can't afford having the server down for 16 hours! Luckily this server was the development server.

How can I know what went wrong? Anyone faced a similar issue with Azure?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. And really there's no way for anyone to be able to figure this out just from "my vm stopped working." It could be *anything*. If you have Azure support, you can open a ticket through your subscription. But StackOverflow isn't going to be the place to have an open-ended discussion/investigation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently nothing is wrong! After the reboot the machine was installing updates to complete the reboot. When I panicked, I have rebooted it again, stopped it, started it again and I have even changed its configuration thinking that it is dead. While in fact it was only installing updates.

Too bad that we cannot disable the automatic reboot or estimate the time it takes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

there is no easy way to troubleshoot this without capturing it in a stuck state.
Sounds like you followed the recommended steps, i.e.:
- Check VM is running (portal/PowerShell/CLI).
- Check endpoints are valid.
- Restart VM
- Force a redeployment by changing the instance size.

To understand why it happened it would be necessary to leave it in a stuck state and open a support case to investigate.

There is work underway to make both self-service diagnosis and redeployment easier for situations like this.